# How to create custom inspector to display generic Stack<T> class

Tags: unity, c#

I have a member that I would like to expose:

```
[Serializable]
private sealed class InputGameObjectStack: Stack<GameObject> {
    public InputGameObjectStack(): base(_InputGameObjectStackSize) {
    }
}
```

Inside the `MonoBehaviour`, I have:

```
[SerializeField]
private InputGameObjectStack _inputGameObjectStack;
```

Inside the editor script, I'm able to fetch the property from the `MonoBehaviour` object (as `SerializedProperty`), but there is *nothing* usable that allows me to traverse through the elements.

Is there any way of showing the constents of the stack in the inspector as immutable (no functionality to push/pop)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Use CustomEditor to display the content of your stack

### For Example

Assume we have the following class `TestScript`

**TestScript**

```
public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour {
    private Stack<GameObject> myStack = new Stack<GameObject>();
    void Start() {
        myStack.Push(new GameObject("Red Arrow"));
        myStack.Push(new GameObject("Green Ball"));
        myStack.Push(new GameObject("Blue Cake"));
    }
}
```

Create another class **inside the existing class** so it could access the private members, like so:

**StackPreview added *inside* TestScript**

```
public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour {
    private Stack<GameObject> myStack = new Stack<GameObject>();
    void Start() {
        myStack.Push(new GameObject("Red Arrow"));
        myStack.Push(new GameObject("Green Ball"));
        myStack.Push(new GameObject("Blue Cake"));
    }

    // This class is inside the TestClass so it could access its private fields
    // this custom editor will show up on any object with TestScript attached to it
    // you don't need (and can't) attach this class to a gameobject
    [CustomEditor(typeof(TestScript))]
    public class StackPreview : Editor {
        public override void OnInspectorGUI() {

            // get the target script as TestScript and get the stack from it
            var ts = (TestScript)target; 
            var stack = ts.myStack;

            // some styling for the header, this is optional
            var bold = new GUIStyle(); 
            bold.fontStyle = FontStyle.Bold; 
            GUILayout.Label("Items in my stack", bold);

            // add a label for each item, you can add more properties
            // you can even access components inside each item and display them
            // for example if every item had a sprite we could easily show it 
            foreach (var item in stack) {
                GUILayout.Label(item.name); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, in the editor you can see just the header (because we're adding items in the start function) - when you run the scene you get a nice list:

[image: Result after running the scene]

Comment: This is great, thank you! I thought about going with this route. But it didn't necessarily work since the field is private.

Comment: I have modified the code to support **private** fields as well.
If this answer is acceptable, please mark it as Accepted. Thanks :-)

Comment: Thanks for the update. I guess there isn't any other way, other than to define the class inside. Messy, but it'll have to do.